# Replacing the Last Ten Blanks With Tabs

Tags: character, vi, replace

I have a file in which each line contains data separated by a single space.  The total number of spaces varies from line to line but is always greater than 10.  I wish to replace only the last ten spaces with tabs.  Any spaces that exist before the last ten are to be left untouched.

How can I do that using vi?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of regular expressions for this purpose.
Regex can be:

```
<Ten Spaces>$
```

or

```
[ ]{10}$
```

$ indicates search from the end.